# How to fix the @ and " buttons because they are switched

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I just got the 20.04 LTS build and I noticed that the  @ and " are switched.
How do I switch them back?

Other than that the build is perfect

Thanks

Comment: You [switch to your preferred keyboard layout](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html).

Answer (score 2):

You have the US International keyboard selected:

[image]

You need to select the English (UK) layout:

[image]

In Settings go to Language and Region and set the input device from there

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is now fixed.

Comment: Brilliant. Perhaps you will also consider marking the answer as accepted which will help others find the solution sometime in the future. Many thanks for the feed back.